# How to send realtime stroke data from InkCanvas UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, uwp

Microsoft documents don't show me how to catch all strokes, other solutions I've looked at were in WPF which has different libraries from UWP's.

1. Do I need to create a separate thread to broadcast strokes?
2. How to catch all strokes with the `InkCanvas` UWP library?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `InkCanvas.InkPresenter` member of the `InkCanvas` and subscribe to its `StrokesCollected` event as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkpresenter.strokescollected):

> Occurs when one or more ink strokes are processed [...] by the application thread.

Comment: wet to dry ? what does that mean. Can Dispatcher solve this ?

Comment: i don't think you care about this, all you want are processed, "dried" inputs I think. Unless that's what you meant by "real-time", maybe?

Comment: Wow this is so confusing, would be glad if there is a example on GitHub constantly write those value to Console

Comment: @strypperjason115 There is a sample project at the following URL - https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk